# Reporting in Visual Studio C# 2010

Tags: c#, reportviewer, visual-studio-express, crystal-reports-2010

Trying to load the Report Viewer tool into the toolbox in the Visual Studio C# Express 2010. I tried everything online including copying the DLL files (using cmd) into the solution's bin directory and all, The tool appears on the silverlight stack of tools but disabled so I still cannot use it. Question is, is there another way of enabling the report viewer tool ? if not is there another way to get reports into my WinForm application ?
Thank you.

Comment: There is a way, have you tried the approach of adding items in the toolbox, by specifying the location of the dll's then?

Comment: And adding the references of these DLLs manually as well...Of course I have but i think the issue is with the express edition. They disabled all reporting services for this edition. Had to use Datagridview. Thank you though